# how set config SolidCp Connection

Tags: websitepanel

I  want to use solidCP  ,So I create a project and I add needed Dlls of SolidCP and I add a Class to config it ,I create a connection for connecting to solidcp ,but I need a sample code for configure it and set user , pass ,... I send my sample Code for You to help me ...

password , username , Apiurl sets for example

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //SolidCP.Providers.ServiceProviderSettings objServerSetiing = new SolidCP.Providers.ServiceProviderSettings() {

    // code stuff..
     };
    SolidCP.Providers.RemoteServerSettings objSetting = new SolidCP.Providers.RemoteServerSettings() {
        ADUsername = "rrrrr",
        ADPassword= "33333333",
        ADEnabled = true    
        };
    SolidCP.Server.Client.ServerProxyConfigurator objConfig = new SolidCP.Server.Client.ServerProxyConfigurator() {
    ServerUrl = "22.22.22.22", ServerPassword = "33333333",ServerSettings = objSetting
        };
     objConfig.Configure(objPackage);
  }
```

thanks a lot ...